# jQuery form auto submission

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to write an autosubmit form (similar to google instant), and right now I am using this script to do so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#string').change(function(){
        var url = $(this).val();
        $('#area').load('cgi/test.pl',{string:url});
    });
});
```

Now the problem with this is that after use finishes typing he will need to click outside the input field. I have tried using `onkeyup` etc. instead of `change` but firstly that will result in insane amount of requests, and secondly if you paste text in the field, it won't work. I have also tried to use javascript `setTimeout` with combination of the script, but couldn't really get it working.

Basically what I am after is autosubmission script that 'detects' when user is still typing (so some kind of delay for the submission) and also can detect when text has been pasted to the input field.

Cheers for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [doTimeout plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/) to implement "debouncing" (example: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/debouncing/).

This way, you can use `keyup`. To account for users pasting text, keep the `change` handler; just invoke the `keyup` handler when `change` fires.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion, will check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't `setTimeout` work? Try doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentTimeout = null;

    $('#string').keyup(handler);
    $('#string').change(handler);

    var handler = function() {    
        if(currentTimeout != null) {
           clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
        }

        currentTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
           var url = $(this).val();
           $('#area').load('cgi/test.pl',{string:url});
        }, 750);
    };
});
```

Comment: The way I implemented it with the `setTimeout` I couldn't get the script to submit the full string, it would always submit the string  missing last one or two characters (depending on how fast I would type), unfortunately I can't find that version of the script. Anyways cheers for the script above, I will test it out asap

Comment: I suspect that would have to do with you not clearing the previous timeout.